# in Segment lambda the segment table is getting populated wrong in QA deployments

Tags: terraform-provider-aws

In Qa lambda table is populating wrong eg: qa_txprser_pub-oid-stg_table-0
it should be qa_txprser_segments_table-0.

In Dev its populating correctly.

my code :
in main.tf

```
 OID_SEGMENT = "${data.aws_dynamodb_table.DynamoDB_oid_stg.name}"
```

in gather.tf

```
data "aws_dynamodb_table" "DynamoDB_segments" {
  name = "${lookup(local.common, "org")}_${lookup(local.common, "busseg")}_${lookup(local.common, "sdlcenv")}_${lookup(local.common, "product")}_${var.ddb_seg_function}_table-0"
}
```

I have checked the table and its working fine in dev. can anyone help me in this.

Comment: How are the local and var values defined? How is this being executed?